# Version being added in my URL's

Tags: magento2, magento2.3.1

I'm moving my site from cloudways to local. I used git to push everything to github, cloned it locally, brought the files into xampp, ran composer install, changed the urls in core_config_data to use localhost, and tried to open the site.
I change the line in validator.php to make the slashes work on Windows.

When I look at the site, a huge mess comes up. When I look at my css urls, they all have a version thrown in

for example:
http://localhost/pub/static/version1573762626/frontend/Smartwave/porto_child/en_US/icon-fonts/css/porto-icons-codes.css

How can I make this work?

I'm including my .gitignore file to see if I'm not pushing enough

```
# Metadata
/.buildpath
/.cache
/.metadata
/.project
/.settings
atlassian*
/nbproject
/sitemap
/.idea
/.gitattributes

# Magento specific configuration
/app/.htaccess
/app/bootstrap.php
/app/autoload.php
/app/functions.php
/app/etc/di.xml
/app/etc/vendor_path.php
/app/etc/NonComposerComponentRegistration.php

# Files re-generated through composer
/CHANGELOG.md
/CONTRIBUTING.md
/COPYING.txt
/ISSUE_TEMPLATE.md
/LICENSE_AFL.txt
/LICENSE.txt
/Gruntfile.js.sample
/nginx.conf.sample
/package.json.sample
/php.ini.sample
/vendor/*
/bin/*
/dev/*
/lib/*
/pub/*
/setup/*
/var/*

# Excludes (or a better alternative might be to symlink this to shared folders
!/pub/media/catalog
!/pub/media/porto
!/pub/media/downloadable
!/var/composer_home
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The version in the URL gets added with the feature "Static Content Signing" https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/cache/static-content-signing.html#static-content-signing

Try to disable the "Static Content Signing" from Admin > Store > Configuration > Advance > Developer > Static File settings as in the screen shot below:

[image]

Also, you can try to do generate the static content using the command `bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f` (where -f is to forcefully do the static-content deploy if you are in developer mode) using shell from your XAMPP and navigating to root directory of your project
[image]

After, above command run `bin/magento cache:clean`

I hope that should help fix your issue.

Comment: I didn't fix the issue. I realized that when I go to /admin, even though I changed the secure and unsecure URLs in core_config_data to localhost, /admin redirects to the online version